# TeeChart WPF Control

Tags: .net, wpf, teechart

Is there a WPF compatible version of TeeChart available for download? I have been using VC# 2010 to develop a WinForms application using the TeeChart Control, and now I want to migrate to VC#2012 WPF. I can pull the winForms Teechart Control into the WPF application without problems, but I cant seem to get the layout to display correclty. More spesifically, it seems as though the size of the TeeChart control is "too big" for the host object on the WPF side...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there's a specific WPF control in TeeChart.WPF.dll assembly. It might be already included in your TeeChart version an is also present in current version. You can check the latest version available for you at the [client download area](http://www.steema.com/clientaccess) or download a fully functional evaluation version [here](http://www.steema.com/download/net).

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the latest version, and I found the WPF Control.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does look like it belongs in TeeChart .NEt

The following notice is found at the project website (https://www.steema.com/version_info/net):

LinePoint series in TeeChart.WPF.dll throws an unhandled